# Reasons of the execution time spikes during N runs of Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm

Tags: java, execution-time, performance, sieve

I developed the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm in Java and I wanted to measure its performance.

Basically I run the "core algorithm" (not the entire application) 5000 times (with a for loop) and measure its execution time.

Here it is the code I used:

```
int N = 100000;
int m;
long[] microseconds = new long[5000];

for (int k = 0; k < 5000; k++) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();

    // Core algorithm
    boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[N + 1];
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        isPrime[i] = true;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i * i <= N; i++) {
        if (isPrime[i]) {
            for (int j = i; (m = i * j) <= N; j++) {
                isPrime[m] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    long end = System.nanoTime();
    microseconds[k] = (end - start) / 1000;
}

// Output of the execution times on file
PrintWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new PrintWriter("ex.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(EratosthenesSieve.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

// iterate through array, write each element of array to file
for (int i = 0; i < microseconds.length; i++) {
    // write array element to file
    writer.print(microseconds[i]);
    // write separator between array elements to file
    writer.print("\n");
}

// done writing, close writer
writer.close();
```

The result is the following:
[image]

As you can see there are some big initial spikes (7913 and 1548) and some "periodical" spikes. How can I explain these spikes? I have already disabled Internet connection (hardware board) and all the possible services running in background (Windows 7; this means no antivirus etc.). Furthermore I set -Xmx and -Xms parameters to a very large quantity of memory. So I'm basically running the application "alone".

I know it's an hard question, but some hints would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have modified my algorithm based on the "beny23" suggestion and now there are no more periodical spikes. However there are some big initial spikes.
[image]

Or (with N=1000 and not anymore N=10000):
[image]

Comment: The spikes will occur when the garbage collector does a collection, you probably would see more consistent performance if you were to reuse your Boolean array.

Comment: You were right, I allocated just once the boolean array and now there are only 5-10 big initial spikes. I'll edit my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely

- you get spikes due to garbage collections, use `-verbose:gc` to see when they occur.
- code runs slower when it has not be warmed up. A loop or method needs to be called 10000 times to trigger a background compilation. You can change this threshold with 
   `-XX:CompileThreshold=10000`
- your machine will have significant jitter due to the way the scheduler works.  Unless you have you thread bound to an isolated CPU you can expect jitter of 2-10 ms for this reason alone.  http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2013/07/micro-jitter-busy-waiting-and-binding.html

I would change your loop to avoid using `*` Its fast on modern CPUs, but not as cheap as `+`

```
for (int j = i, m = i * i; m <= N; j++, m += i) {
```